# For each loop does not operate as expected

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, each

I have two sheets in excel, one is a board with several cells with numbers inside, and the other is references (that have the numbers in previous board) and i need to write in same line of the references where are the cells located.
[image of the first board where are the references](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjHzs.png)
[image of the excel sheet that i have to write the location of each reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqeMU.png)
[my vba code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LZgg.png)
Example:

[image]

The arm8.png is the board and local.png is where i write de localizations of the cells

```
Option Explicit

Sub ciclo()

    Dim FindString As String
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim matrixVal As Range

    Set matrixVal = Sheets("Localizações").Range("B1")
    FindString = matrixVal

    For Each Rng In matrixVal

        If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then

            With Sheets("Arm8").Range("A1:J10")

                Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                                After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                MatchCase:=False)

                If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                    'Application.Goto Rng, False
                    'MsgBox Rng.Column & " - " & Rng.Row
                Else
                    MsgBox "Nothing found"
                End If

            End With

            With Sheets("Localizações")
                .Range("C1:C9").Value = Rng.Column
                .Range("D1:D9").Value = Rng.Row
            End With

        End If

    Next Rng

End Sub
```

I expected the output in local.png to be column C and D

2 - 9
2 - 7
2 - 8
2 - 4
5 - 4
7 - 4
5 - 9
9 - 7
9 - 0

Comment: You have set `matrixval`, to be one single cell. So your `For-Each` loop will only run once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, as I said in my comment, this:

```
Set matrixVal = Sheets("Localizações").Range("B1")
```

sets `matrixVal` as one single cell (B1 to be precise), so your `For-Each` loop doesn't have any cells to loop through apart from this single cell, so it will only run once.

Second, the `FindString` needs to be updated inside the loop, otherwise you'll be searching for the same value over and over.

Finally, you shouldn't update the `Rng` variable inside the loop because you are already using it to loop through a range. You need a second variable of type `Range`.

Your code should look like:

```
 Sub ciclo()

    Dim FindString As String
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim matrixVal As Range

    Set matrixVal = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Localizacoes").Range("B1:B9")

    For Each cell In matrixVal
        FindString = cell.Value

        If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then

            With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Arm8").Range("A1:J10")

                Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                                After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                MatchCase:=False)

                If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Localizacoes")
                        .Cells(cell.Row, "C").Value = Rng.Column
                        .Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value = Rng.Row
                    End With
                Else
                    MsgBox "Nothing found"
                End If

            End With

        End If

    Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Glad I could help!